# Is it possible?- Link Oracle table to MS Access, Import linked table to Excel from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm able to create a linked table from Oracle to Access, and I'm able to import non-linked tables to Excel from Access (i.e. actual Access tables), but is it possible to link a table from oracle to access, and then open the link in Excel?

Going through the regular process of "Get Data", or Powerquery, or Powerpivot in Excel, no linked tables appear for selection.

Comment: Not super familiar with linked tables in Access, but would that be functionally different then connecting directly to the Oracle DB from Excel? As I understand it, a "linked" table means Access is only maintaining a connection to the linked DB and not holding data from the linked DB locally.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be different than connecting excel to oracle, but I noticed that the database runs abnormally slow this way. This linked table exercise is just to test if it would work any better using Access as an intermediary instead (doubtful)